# Unable to Make Typescript Work in Codepen

Tags: typescript, rxjs, codepen

I've made the simplest possible Codepen to test out some Typescript/RxJS stuff, and I get a console error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

For reference, the entire pen is just this line (with RxJS included and Typescript compilation turned on):

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

The pen is at https://codepen.io/bikeshop/pen/LaGWvE . Anyone had any experience making this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to those APIs (import, export, require) on codepen because it runs in the browser, and those are a part of node. If you want to use node modules in some sort of playground environment I'd suggest [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages), which gives you access to what is essentially a stateless server and allows you to write code in tons of different languages. You can choose TypeScript and get started from there. Any import statements will automatically install the required dependency, so:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

will install rxjs when you first run your code.

Answer (score 0):

It tripped me up at first, but if you add a package via [the settings menu](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/using-javascript-libraries/) then it automatically is available in scope.

E.g. I added `aws` from that menu, and then could use `AWS` in the **JS** pane without any `require`/`import` statement.